# IPython threw an exception in reading file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I successfully ran this script in Python, but IPython notebook threw an exception. 
What could be the problem?

```
import os
from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

command = "java -cp \"C:\mallet-2.0.7\class;C:\mallet-2.0.7\lib\mallet-deps.jar\" cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --train true --model-file nouncrf train.txt"
p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell = True)

for line in p.stdout:
     print line


Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: train.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger.main(SimpleTagger.java:504)
```

Comment: where is `train.txt`? what's the printout of your `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: IPython isn't throwing the exception, it is simply reporting the error coming from the Java program it has been told to run. Also you would be well-advised to use raw string constants for Windows filenames (or at least double the backslashes so there is no risk they will be interpreted as string escapes. The error means there is some difference int he two environments, but we can't really tell you what that might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the question is not related to Python at all, as it is a Java exception, not a Python one. Most probably, the file (`train.txt`) is looked for in a current directory. When you run your script in Python, the current directory may differ from what it is in IPython. Is the Java program able to accept absolute file path? If yes, you may specify the absolute path in command line for Java program.